# Angular Date Format

Tags: angularjs, angular-date-format

I am getting a date as `Mar 30 2017 12:23AM` from a web service and need to display it as `2017 Mar 30`.

I have tried as this `{{order.created_date | date:'yyyy MMM dd'}}`.

But output is `Mar 30 2017 12:23AM`.

What could be the issue?

Comment: may be you are storing date in string and applying the date filter. it will show you the same as it was earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Something else must be wrong with your code. `date` filter does work in angular the same way.

Check for your date not being a `String` since it is the most possible other scenario.

Here's `date` filter working for `yyyy MMM dd` format.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.mydate = new Date()
  $scope.stringdate = String($scope.mydate)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<pre>mydate: {{mydate | date: 'yyyy MMM dd'}}</pre>
<pre>stringdate: {{stringdate | date: 'yyyy MMM dd'}}</pre>
</div>
```